# Auto Layouts in Swift: 'String' is not identical to 'NSObject'

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am following the tutorial on this page:

http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/

I got to this point in the code:

```
let dict = ["list":list]
let lcH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[list(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: dict)
```

And that last line is producing this error (with an arrow pointing to `dict`):

```
'String' is not identical to 'NSObject'
```

I originally was trying to convert the [Objective C code in this tutorial](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/) over to Swift, and I got the exact same error in the same place. Back then I thought it was a result of me converting the code over incorrectly, but now Im following this Swift tutorial and getting the exact same result.

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>option</kbd> click on `dict`.  That will tell you the type that Swift has inferred it to be.  I'm guessing it is `[String: UIView?]`.  The values in the dictionary can't be optionals, so you need to unwrap `list` when creating `dict`:

```
let dict = ["list":list!]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this - now when I am adding the Constraint it is complaining that `'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'NSLayoutConstraint'`

Comment: `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat()` returns an array of constraints.  Its type is `[AnyObject]` - array of `AnyObject`.  You need to call `addConstraints` instead of `addConstraint`.  The reason it returns an array of constraints is that the visual format can and often does lead to multiple constraints being created.

Comment: Just that little 's' on the end.... Shaking my fist at the screen. Thanks vacawama